# Counter HashMap to remove less counter value

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Is there any HashMap implementation that is bounded and remove least map value when the limit is reached?

For example,

```
    int size = 3;
    Map<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(size);
    Object[] objects = {'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'};
    for (Object o : objects) {
        if (map.containsKey(o)) {
            map.put(o, map.get(o) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(o, 1);
        }
    }
```

After this operations I would have the map has:

```
{{a,3},{c,2},{d,1}}
```

The order is not necessarily to be retained, note that the b is removed because when the d is inserted the map would be full and the entry that has the least value is removed.

Comment: can you please show us an example and clarify more? note that the Map is not ordered so what want exactly?

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: so it can be also `{{a,3},{b,1},{d,1}}` note the `{b,1}` no?

Comment: What if you add `{e,0}` is it `{d,1}` or `{e,0}` that will be removed ?

Comment: @YCF_L , no it can't, because the map is full when d is inserted, then the map will remove the entry with least value which is b entry.

Comment: This is basically a counter of occurrence with boundaries. So a newer entry will always have a value of `1`, which always gave the last entry a possible occurence to be removed. **If** you want to remove the smallest value in the map before insertion, **please state it**. The problem I see is once every key will have a value > 1. The `keySet` will never change since the smallest value will always be the latest added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LinkedHashMap` to achieve this. Normally you'd use it for a LRU cache, and the implementation isn't very effective, but this is a `Map` that allows you to limit the amount of entries inside.

```
new LinkedHashMap<Object, Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<Object, Integer> eldest) {
        // Remove one of smallest values when going over 100
        if(size() > 100) {
            Optional<Map.Entry<Object, Integer>> min = this.entrySet().stream()
                        .min(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));

            min.ifPresent((k) -> remove(k.getKey()));
        }
        return false; // Always return false, so map doesn't remove entries
    }
};
```

Comment: @AxelH if you return `true` it will remove the eldest entry (i.e. head). That's why we return `false`.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed my terms. I mean you could remove the last entry added since this will be executed after the insertion. This might required to store the last inserted item in a variable (overriding `put` and `putAll`) to be sure to not select it. (if the behavior is not the one expected)

Comment: @AxelH the idea is to remove the key with the smallest value. Not the last or first entry added. Well, in the above code the size would overflow only after a new entry is inserted, so it would have a max value of `1`, but that's not the kind of optimization I'd put here (for readability purposes).

Comment: The solution works fine, but any put operation will cost us O(n), this is unaffordable to do.

Comment: @Aladdin are you claiming your other code is so optimal that this would appear as a performance hotspot? I have a hard time believing that, considering the code you've shown.

Comment: I have added my concern on the question directly @Kayaman, you logic is correct, it just seems the requirements is forgetting one small detail.

Comment: @AxelH ah now I understand what you mean. Although, the iteration order should be from the eldest entry to the newest one as it's a `LinkedHashMap` with insertion order.

Comment: I might have been unclear with my bad english, sorry about that ;) It would be fine until you reach a value > 1 for each `Entry.value`. Then the smallest value will always be the newest. (this is an occurrence counter, so a new `Entry` will always have a value of 1). At this point, the `keySet` will never change. This is when it is important to know if the newest `Entry` could be removed or not.

Comment: You know, when `size()` is bigger than `100`, the optional can’t be empty. You can simplify the entire operation to `if(size() > 100) remove(Collections.min(entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey());`…

Answer (score 0):

This sound pretty uncommon and I don't think that you could find such an implementation. Depending on your use case you could possibly use a queue.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is a Map whose intent is to *map* a key with a value. The key is unique.

For example you can map `Integer roll` to `Student student`. For this you can have a HashMap

`Map <Integer, Student> studentMap = new HashMap <>()`

In your case it seams you need a container of maxSize defined. Based on your preferred parameters (least accessed, or most old object) you can remove the item in case the current size is equal to defined maxSize and you need to insert a new item.  This is more like a queue. You can implement your own queue by wrapping an array, or LinedList, ArrayList, etc. (Based on your actual requirements).

Just because HashMap can accepts 2 generic parameters so forcing it as a solution to a problem is not a good idea. Select the right data structure and may be use it to create your custom data structure to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a frequency table containing only the most recent added frequencies. *MRU tables* would be the keyword. You should look at *guava* and other libraries.

Doing it yourself:

```
for (Object o : objects) {
    map.merge(o, 1, Integer::sum); // Update frequency
    if (map.size() > maxSize) {
       map.remove(map.entrySet().stream()
           .sorted(Comparators.compare(Map.Entry<Object, Integer>::getValue))
           .map(Map.Entry<Object, Integer>::getKey)
           .findFirst()
           .get());
    }
}
```

This accepts an overflow of 1 (in a non-concurrent context), walks through *all entries* (slow) and removes the minimal value's key.

Comment: `Comparators.compare(Map.Entry<Object, Integer>::getValue)` does not compile, it should be `Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<Object, Integer>::getValue)`, but you can use the much simpler `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` instead. And generally, there’s rarely a need to specify explicit types with method references, e.g. `.map(Map.Entry::getKey)` works fine.

Comment: @Holger of course, that much better I leave it for someoneelses answer

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own implementation Map

```
class MyHashMap<K> extends HashMap<K, Integer> {

private int maxSize;

public MyHashMap(int maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
}

@Override
public Integer put(K key, Integer value) {
    Integer v = super.put(key, value);

    if (maxSize < size()) {
        entrySet().stream()
                  .filter(entry -> !entry.getKey().equals(key))
                  .min(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
                  .ifPresent(entry -> remove(entry.getKey()));
    }

    return v;
}
```